# TTStyledTextLabel

Tags: iphone, three20, ttstyledtextlabel

I'm trying to get this control to work with a hypertext link with not much success.  I have looked at TTCalaog and tried to replecate but does not work.

I have this working as far as displaying the hypertext link but it does not fire.

TTStyledTextLabel* label = [[[TTStyledTextLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 315, 175)] autorelease];

NSString* labelText = @"This should work";

label.text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:labelText lineBreaks:NO URLs:YES];

[self.view addSubview:label];

I thing I am missing the point here perhaps with the placement of the google url?  I have seen a post on this forum that makes use of custom-uri://some/url that is then set up in TTURLMap and TTNavigator, but I need to open a url from the hypertext in a webview so I need the url to run a method in my class that creates my webview controller etc.

I have tried to cusomise TTURLMap to work without a TTNavigator but completely pickled?

Any help gratefullt appreciated ;-)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've just found myself a solution to catch the clicked URL on a TTStyledTextLabel. I hope this could help in your case too.

This's what I have done.

**1. Create TTNavigator**

```c
    TTNavigator *navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
    navigator.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeNone;
    navigator.delegate = self;
```

**2. Create TTNavigatorDelegate**

As you assigned self as delegate of the navigator object. Therefore, please remember to add  protocol in the header file .h before you continue.

In the implementation, create this method

```c
    - (BOOL) navigator:(TTBaseNavigator *)navigator shouldOpenURL:(NSURL *)URL {
        // Now you can catch the clicked URL, and can do whatever with it
        // For Example: In my case, I take the query of the URL
        // If no query is available, let the app open the URL in Safari
        // If there's query, get its value and process within the app

        NSString *query = URL.query;

        if (query == nil) {
            return YES;
        } else {
            // process the query
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps! Please vote for me if this helps to solve your issue!

Best Regards,

Thang